# How do we reload a collection view on its did select item delegate?

Tags: swift, swift3

I cant reload my collection view from its did Select Item. When I reload the collection view, the delegates `numberOfItemsInSection` and `numberOfSections` gets called. However, the `cellForItemAt` doesn't gets called. Why is this? .Is it inappropriate to reload a collection view from its own `didSelectItemAt`

My code is as below

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    indexSelectedCell = indexPath.row

    collectionView.performBatchUpdates({

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            self.collAvailableLanguages.reloadData()
        })

    }, completion: nil)
}
```

My requirement is that I want to highlight a label in selected cell and unhighlight the previous cell. I did(try) it by keeping track of current selected cell index. My code is

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "LanguageCell", for: indexPath) as? BaashaLanguageCell {
        cell.lblLanStr.text = arrAvailbleLanDemo[indexPath.row]

        if indexPath.row != 0 || indexPath.row != arrAvailbleLanDemo.count - 1 {
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        }

        if indexSelectedCell == indexPath.row {
            print("OK")
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

            switch isHostLanVC {
            case true:
                cell.lblLanStr.textColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x599441)
            default:
                cell.lblLanStr.textColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x5F90CB)

            }
        } else {
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        }

        return cell
    } else {
        return BaashaLanguageCell()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method `reloadItems(at:)` should do what you want.

```
class MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath? // Save the whole index path. It's easier.

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var reloadIndexPaths = [indexPath]

        // If an cell is already selected, then it needs to be deselected.
        // Add its index path to the array of index paths to be reloaded.
        if let deselectIndexPath = selectedIndexPath { reloadIndexPaths.append(deselectIndexPath) }

        selectedIndexPath = indexPath

        collectionView.reloadItems(at: reloadIndexPaths)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "LanguageCell", for: indexPath) as? Baasha_LanguageCell else {
            return Baasha_LanguageCell()
        }

        if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
            // yes
        } else {
            // no
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: This works fine :) .  Do you know why does my collection view didn't reload when I called collectionView.reloadData?

Comment: @Jeesson_7 I've had odd issues with `reloadData()` in the past. I can't remember off the top of my head, but I think I had to call `invalidateLayout()` on the collection view layout first.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're doing any why you're doing it but it is a little overkill as you're able to achieve all of this without a reload and all inside of your didSelect method. You'll want to also have selected state variable inside your cell class like so:

```
var isSelected: Bool = false
```

//

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? Baasha_LanguageCell {

        if indexPath.item == 0 {

            if cell.isSelected == true {
                // SELECTING CELL
                cell.backgroundColor = .red
            } else {
                // DESELECTING CELL
                cell.backgroundColor = .white
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Here selection of one cell is not dependent on another. In my case I want to unhighlight the previous selected cell while I select a new one. And although I did change the colour, its not reflected in CollectionView for some reason